# Groovy max value in array

Tags: java, groovy

The goal of this code is simply to find the max of the numbers in list a and multiply it by 1.5
The first input decides the amount of numbers the user enters.
The second input is a double which are the numbers.
I have used an array to collect my numbers and find max from it.

I have written the below code however I am not getting the right max value.
Can you please let me know where I am going wrong? and also please feel to comment if I am not following right way of coding as I am pretty new to it.

My data is

```
10
750.55
1555.99
524.12
5268.00
789.4569  // program shows this a max value
1245.78
124.556
175.56
1796.46
7564.994
```

Below is my code:

```
class Main {
    static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in)
        def NoofTrans = Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine())
        def Transamt = [NoofTrans]
        for (int i = 0; i < NoofTrans; i++) {

            Transamt[i]=sc.nextLine()
        }

        def Creditlimit
        println Transamt.max()

        Creditlimit=Transamt.max().toDouble()
        def Creditlimit1=(Creditlimit*5)
        println Creditlimit1
        println Creditlimit1.round(2)
    }
}
```

My output is below

```
789.4569
1184.19
```

whereas it should be

```
7564.994
11347.49
```

Comment: Your `Transmt` list combines numbers and text, so finding max numbers can't have predictable results

Comment: Thanks ernest, however I have only entered numbers in my input

Comment: No. `Transamt[i]=sc.nextLine()` adds a string to the list. You should either use `nextDouble()` like the first entry or convert to `double` before adding to the list.

Comment: Maybe you should use `Double.parseDouble()`, because these numbers are not integers

Comment: It worked. Thanks @ernest_k and Victor Herasme Perez

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems:

1 - You've mixed numbers and strings in the same list. So the max you found did not use numerical comparison. You need to use `nextDouble()` for Scanner to give you a number:

```
Transamt[i] = sc.nextDouble();
```

2 - Your code is multiplying max by `5` whereas you want to multiply it by `1.5`. This just produced unexpected results.

Here's the full code:

```
class MainGroovy {
    static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in)
        def NoofTrans = Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine())
        def Transamt = [NoofTrans]

        for (int i = 0; i < NoofTrans; i++) {
            Transamt[i] = sc.nextDouble()
        }

        println Transamt.max()

        def Creditlimit = Transamt.max()
        def Creditlimit1 = Creditlimit * 1.5
        println Creditlimit1
        println Creditlimit1.round(2)
    }
}
```

When executed with your input, the output is:

```
7564.994
11347.491
11347.49
```